DCC Fatal Error F2039 Could not create output file 'Welcome_p.exe' - Need Assistance
I'm currently working on a Delphi project and I keep encountering the following error when trying to compile my project:
[DCC Fatal Error] F2039 Could not create output file 'Welcome_p.exe'
This issue started after I deleted my App Data folder. I factory resetted my whole computer and left my computer with some Delphi professionals who re-installed the software for me. Here are some details about my environment:

Delphi Version: Delphi 2010
Operating System: Windows 11 Home - Version: 23H2

Steps I've already tried:

Checked file permissions to ensure I have write access to the output directory.
Verified that the file is not in use by any other process.
Temporarily disabled my antivirus software to rule out interference.

Despite these efforts, the error persists. I am hesitant to make further changes on my own. Could anyone provide guidance on how to resolve this issue?
Thank you in advance for your assistance!
Best regards,
Abdullah
I tried to click on the Green Run Button and I expected it to execute the Application file Welcome_p.exe but It gave me an error instead stating:
[DCC Fatal Error] F2039 Could not create output file 'Welcome_p.exe'

Just remove Welcome_p.exe using Windows Explorer or a command-prompt window.

Cleaning the project (right click on project and press clean) often works too, without needing to leave the Delphi environment. Nevertheless it is annoying when it happens.
